# Gitlab CI: git diff shows old modifications

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am working on a script launched by gitlab's CI that detects primitive types in code using a git diff.

My script uses the command : `git diff origin/master ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}`

It's working perfectly on local ie: git diff returns the good changes; linked to my branch.

On the CI git diff is returning a (very) lot of changes that or not linked to my branch.

Do you have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem using `git diff origin/master...origin/${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}`